# Try and catch is not throwing message and handling the issue

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to post something to my API regularly in my app lets say every 3 minutes and in return I some data sometimes, data does not get delivered and I found the data nil, that's why I tried to put a `try/catch` concept with below code:

```
        var err: NSError?
        var json:NSDictionary!
        do {
            json =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary
        }
        catch {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                postCompleted(succeeded: false, msg: "Logged in.")

            })
        }
```

However catch statement never get to work and each time I get nil, app crash inside `do`.

Comment: perhaps `data` is nil? the unwrapped nil is not an exception

Comment: Completely agree with the point above (was just writing the same) also worth wrapping the cast to NSDictionary in an if let or guard statement to make sure your json object is initialized correctly before you use it.

Comment: can you let me know how to write it?

Comment: Hopefully Wei Chen's answer gives you what you need regarding checking on data using a guard. You can do something similar for json like this     guard json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary { return } or if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as? NSDictionary { safely work with json }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public class func JSONObjectWithData(data: NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject`

Because `data: NSData` is not unwrapped. if data is nil, function will be crash. You add

`guard let data = data else {
        return
    }`

And **try/catch** Because this function may throws error. If data encoding format is incorrect,this function will throws error,you can catch in catch.

hopefully it will be useful to you.